# Is there something odd about this phrase: "these problems"?

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote this sentence:

> Beside the main content, a web page may comprise of distracting parts such as ads, animations, logos, that can degrade the readability of the main content and pose difficulties to readers.  In addition to these factors, colour contrast, font style, letter spacing, layout, line height and length of the content are among of the other factors that affect the readability of a web page. **These problems could be more serious** for specific population such as older adults, visually impaired users, non-native readers (those reading a page in a non-native language).

I guess the bold phrase should be common when someone want to say, the problem is more serious for specific group. but I wonder the Google results for it is just [2 case](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22These%20problems%20could%20be%20more%20serious%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#).

Are there better alternatives for my purpose?

---

**Update**: As I searched more "the problem could be more serious" (119000) and "the problem is more serious" (about 8 million results). I am convinced that I'd better use the latter phrase, but why so much difference? is "these problems" that odd?

Comment: Pay no attention at all to those "estimates" Google provides at the top. They're meaningless.

Comment: This looks like proofreading to me (or a request for writing advice, equally Off Topic). Grammatically there's nothing wrong with your highlighted text, though I'd definitely change *specific **populations*** to *specific **individuals*** or similar. And if you want to sound more "formal" you might consider *could be exacerbated* rather than *could be more serious*.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, but the difference is very considerable. I guess "the problem" is more common, even when there are multiple problems. they look all one issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I also have a side question, in the last sentence, we may say "those reading a page in their native language", but why when it is "non-native" we can't use possessive pronoun. Beside, I myself think "the problem", "the issue" ... are more common.

Comment: @Ahmad: It would be perfectly reasonable for *your* text to refer to ***this** problem* - the (single) problem being the presence within a web page of characteristics which detract from its readability.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you mean "this problem" instead of "the problem", which was my last revision? I also agree *this* sound better, beside I found about 400,000 results for it too.

Comment: Note, before you go any further with this, that " colour contrast, font style, letter spacing, layout, line height and length of the content" are not inherently "problems". They are merely variables which can take problematic values.

Comment: Again: pay no attention to Google's estimated hits. Nobody knows what the algorithm is, and it's insanely unreliable: I've known Google to estimate hundreds of thousands and only be able to report forty or fifty actual hits.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, I agree, the problem is "web page readability issues"

Comment: @StoneyB yes I also experienced it when the number is high, this will be revealed when one navigate several  pages. but in my case the pages were just 2 in the first. you can refer to yourself, I guess you less use "these problems" than "this problem" specially with "could"

Comment: So you need to get *these problems* in *before* you mention those factors. Perhaps something like "These problems, and others created by unconsidered choices in colour contrast, font style ... may be even more serious for ..."

Comment: Just for instance: When I look at the actual hits on "This problem could be more serious" I get 60, of which more than half are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The use of subjunctive mood ('could' instead of 'can') is probably due to the unlikeliness of "specific population" visiting that page.  The use of 'can/could be' instead of 'is' most likely due to the same notion - possibility.

The problem does not exist unless we have evidence to support it.  If there is no evidence but speculation, and the conditions are likely to lead to the problem, then the usual way to say is "can be".  If the circumstances are questionable for the problem to arise, or predicated on some coincidence, then "could be" is advised.

Compare:

> I have an uncle with a short temper who is 70.  My uncle **is** an old grumpy man.
>
> I have an aunt who is looking for a husband.  With her looking, my uncle **can be** an old grumpy man.
>
> My mother had a brother who died in his 20s.  Had he lived, my uncle **could be** an old grumpy man.

As to your question about the possibility to improve, perhaps, but it is quite OK as it is.  And it depends on what exactly you would like to say.